# NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(Ljava/lang/String;)Lokhttp3/HttpUrl when using retrofit 2

Tags: java

I am using retrofit 2 to send a http request, code like this:

```
            ReconcileService service = RetrofitUtil.InitRetrofitOkhttp().create(ReconcileService.class);
            Call<ResponseBody> call = service.page(request);
            ResponseBody body = call.execute().body();
            String str = new String(body.bytes(), "UTF-8");
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Response response = mapper.readValue(str, Response.class);
```

this is the retrofit initial code:

```
public static Retrofit InitRetrofitOkhttp() {
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.readTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.writeTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        builder.retryOnConnectionFailure(true);
        Config config = ConfigService.getAppConfig();
        String baseUrl = config.getProperty("robot.retrofit.base-url", "127.0.0.1");
        OkHttpClient client = builder.build();
        Retrofit.Builder retrofitBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder();
        retrofitBuilder.client(client);
        retrofitBuilder.baseUrl(baseUrl);
        Retrofit sRetrofit = retrofitBuilder.build();
        return sRetrofit;
    }
```

but when running this code, it give me tips:

```
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_212]
Caused by: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(Ljava/lang/String;)Lokhttp3/HttpUrl;
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055) [spring-webmvc-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.HttpUrl.get(Ljava/lang/String;)Lokhttp3/HttpUrl;
    at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:492) ~[retrofit-2.8.1.jar!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.misc.biz.common.RetrofitUtil.InitRetrofitOkhttp(RetrofitUtil.java:42) ~[soa-misc-biz-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.illidan.controller.impl.tenant.ReconcilationController.getRes(ReconcilationController.java:38) ~[classes!/:na]
    at com.sportswin.soa.illidan.controller.impl.tenant.ReconcilationController.tenantPage(ReconcilationController.java:31) ~[classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) [spring-web-5.1.13.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.13.RELEASE]
```

I try to find answer from internet but all told to upgrade the okhttp version. But now my okhttp version already 4.0, this is my gradle config:

```
api("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.0")
api "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.8.1"
```

so where is the problem and what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I check the reference using gradle command like this:

```
gradle :soa-illidan:soa-illidan-service:dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath|grep -v "(*)"|grep -C 10 "okhttp"
```

and find the okhttp jar actual version is 3.8.1:

```
$ gradle :soa-illidan:soa-illidan-service:dependencies --configuration runtimeClasspath|grep -v "(*)"|grep -C 10 "okhttp"
\--- project :soa-illidan:soa-illidan-api
     +--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
     +--- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
     +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9
     +--- project :soa-misc-biz
     |    +--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
     |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
     |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9
     |    +--- com.github.pagehelper:pagehelper:5.1.11
     |    |    \--- com.github.jsqlparser:jsqlparser:2.0 -> 2.1
     |    +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.0.0 -> 3.8.1
     |    |    +--- com.squareup.okio:okio:2.2.2
     |    |    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.60 -> 1.2.71
     |    |    |         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.2.71
     |    |    |         \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     |    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.8.1
     |    |    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.8.1
     |    |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5 -> 2.8.6
     |    +--- project :soa-misc
     |    |    +--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
     |    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4
Errors occurred while build effective model from /Users/dolphin/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.alibaba/druid/1.1.9/e6a9ff9e84dd1c498d9e12373331fbacd92d330a/druid-1.1.9.pom:
    'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.alibaba:jconsole:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/jconsole.jar in com.alibaba:druid:1.1.9
    'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.alibaba:tools:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar in com.alibaba:druid:1.1.9
```

so I add this in the `buil.gradle` to force using 4.0.0 version of okhttp:

```
 resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
               
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.squareup.okhttp3') {
                    details.useVersion "4.0.0"
                }
            }
        }
```

problem solved. hope helps for you! The full config look like this:

```
buildscript {
    apply from: "${rootProject.projectDir}/common.gradle"

    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.11.RELEASE"
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.arenagod.gradle:mybatis-generator-plugin:1.4"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'application'
    id 'maven-publish'
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.6.7"
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "6.4.3"
    id 'com.github.ayltai.spring-graalvm-native-plugin' version '1.4.10'
    id "org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin" version "1.3.4"

}

apply from: "${rootProject.projectDir}/common.gradle"

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'io.freefair.lombok'
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
    apply plugin: 'java-library'
    apply plugin: "idea"
    apply plugin: "io.spring.dependency-management"
    apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
    apply plugin: 'org.springdoc.openapi-gradle-plugin'


    configurations.all {
        exclude group: "ch.qos.logback", module: "logback-classic"
        exclude group: "ch.qos.logback", module: "logback-core"
        exclude group: "org.apache.logging.log4j", module: "log4j-to-slf4j"
        /**
         * why exclude the gson?
         * https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/1826
         */
        // exclude group: "com.google.code.gson", module: "gson"

        // check for updates every build
        resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'

        // check for updates every build
        resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'

        resolutionStrategy {
            eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.github.jsqlparser') {
                    details.useVersion "2.1"
                }
                //if (details.requested.group == 'redis.clients' && details.requested.name == 'jedis' ) {
                //    details.useVersion("4.0.0")
                //}
                if (details.requested.group == 'org.springframework.data' && details.requested.name == 'spring-data-redis' ) {
                    details.useVersion("2.7.1")
                }
                //exclude group: "org.springframework.data", module: "spring-data-redis"
                if (details.requested.group == 'org.postgresql' && details.requested.name == 'postgresql' ) {
                    details.useVersion("42.2.23")
                }
                if (details.requested.group == 'org.apache.logging.log4j' && details.requested.name == 'log4j-api' ) {
                    details.useVersion("2.17.0")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        if (project.hasProperty("buildEnv") && project.getProperties().get("buildEnv") == "github") {
            mavenCentral()
        } else {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
        annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
        testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
        testImplementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}"
        api "$rootProject.ext.dependencies.log4j"
        api "$rootProject.ext.dependencies.slfj2Log4j"
        api "$rootProject.ext.dependencies.collections4"
        api "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:${commonColleciton3Version}"
        implementation "$rootProject.ext.dependencies.mybatisGeneratorCore"
        implementation "$rootProject.ext.dependencies.itfswMybatisGeneratorPlugin"
        testImplementation group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '7.4.0'
    }

    dependencyManagement {
        imports {
            mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:$rootProject.ext.version.springCloudVersion"
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    sourceCompatibility = 11
    targetCompatibility = 11
    def defaultEncoding = 'UTF-8'
    compileJava {
        options.encoding = defaultEncoding
    }
    compileTestJava {
        options.encoding = defaultEncoding
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
    }

    /**
     * remove aliyun repo config from ~/.gradle/init.gradle into project
     * avoid to force other project in machine use aliyun
     * some international project could not fetch dependencies from aliyun
     */
    repositories {
        def PROXY_REPOSITORY_URL = 'https://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public'
        all { ArtifactRepository repo ->
            if(repo instanceof MavenArtifactRepository){
                def url = repo.url.toString()
                if (url.startsWith('https://repo1.maven.org/maven2')) {
                    project.logger.lifecycle "Repository ${repo.url} replaced by $PROXY_REPOSITORY_URL."
                    remove repo
                }
            }
        }
        maven {
            url PROXY_REPOSITORY_URL
        }
        /****** Release Repo ********/
        maven {
            credentials {
                username System.getenv("ALIYUN_REPO_USERNAME")
                password System.getenv("ALIYUN_REPO_PASSWORD")
            }
            url 'https://packages.aliyun.com/maven/repository/2236707-release-REsSq7/'
        }
        /****** Snapshot Repo ********/
        maven {
            credentials {
                username System.getenv("ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_NAME")
                password System.getenv("ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_PASSWORD")
            }
            url 'https://packages.aliyun.com/maven/repository/2236707-snapshot-lUlWG7/'
        }
    }
}
```

this is the `build.gradle` file location:

[image]

Comment: where to put that

Comment: I have pasted the full `build.gradle` config to help you understand where to put the config. @Akashkumar

Comment: i tried pasting it in android block but throws error again i tried outside of android block still it throws error. can you please guid where to put exactly in build.gradle

Comment: this is a java project with multi module, not an android project. @Akashkumar